# pixelated image during css transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

When the transition below occurs, the image becomes pixelated for a second or two. Do you know why it happens and how to fix it ?

```css
#picture {
  height: 96px;
  width: 96px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
}
#picture:hover {
  height: 106px;
  width: 106px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://stefandigital.com/yp/images/icons/man01.png" id="picture" />
```

---

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBNamq)

Comment: Do you have an example or anything?

Comment: might help if you could add what you have to a codepen,plunkr

Comment: see the circle border ? it gets pixelated for a second right after the transition
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBNamq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing `width` and `height` properties, use [**`transform`**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform/) and the [**`scale()`**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/scale/) function.

Performance-wise, using `transform` will result in a better FPS because it avoids browser reflow.

```css
#picture {
  height: 96px;
  width: 96px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.05s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.05s ease-out;
  -o-transition: transform 0.05s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.05s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#picture:hover {
  transform: scale(1.141);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://stefandigital.com/yp/images/icons/man01.png" id="picture" />
```

---

### [Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbNdQw)

---

**Notes:**

- Avoid using the keyword `all` in the `transition` property, targeting only the properties that are going to be transitioned helps in performance.
- Unless the [**`transition-timing-fuction`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) changes in the hover state, the `transition` property does not need to be defined in the `:hover` pseudo-class.
- [**`transform-origin`**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform-origin/) is used to change the origin of the transformation of the element.

Answer (score 0):

The original images' size was way too big. It was 2000x2000 px, I brought it down to 128x128. Now the pixels are gone! But thank you guys for the optimization